# Connect 3 monitors to Macbook Pro retina early 2015 13"

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hdmi, displayport

I've seen multiple system setups where people connected 3 external displays to their macbook pro retina 13". So I bought 2 Mini-Displayport to VGA and 1 HDMI to VGA adapters. The adapters are working fine, full HD resolutions works great but I cann only connect 2 external monitors. I can use 2 monitors via Mini-DP or 1 with HDMI and 1 with Mini-DP but when I connect all 3 one monitor will keep the black screen.

I read somewhere that I should use active Mini-DP to VGA adapters to use all 3 external screens.
Do you have some experience with this or have another solution?

Comment: Where did you see it?

Answer (score 2):

According to [Everymac](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i5-2.7-13-early-2015-retina-display-specs.html)

> This model supports a simultaneous maximum resolution up to 3840x2160 on two external displays via Thunderbolt 2. Alternately, it can support a single display up to 3840x2160 via Thunderbolt 2 and a single 1080p display at up to 60 Hz, 3840x2160 at 30 Hz, or 4096x2160 at 24 Hz via HDMI.
>
> Also see: [How many external displays can the Retina Display MacBook Pro models support?](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/macbook-pro-retina-display-faq/macbook-pro-retina-display-how-to-manually-switch-graphics.html#extdisplays) What is the maximum supported resolution of each? Are adapters required?

Comment: Well its 3 full HD 1080p displays and since they're also connected to my other pc via HDMI I want to connect them to the mac using the vga interface..